# Import Powershell DNS server module

Tags: powershell, scripting, dns

I am deploying some virtual machines by script, and I would like to check if the FQNA that I adding to my script is already created in the DNS records.

I found the commands to do this, but I can't find what Powershell module I need to use these commands.

Found DNSserver and others, but this doesn't work and I am a bit confused which module should I import/install to be able to use Powershell DNS commands to use like get-dnsserverresourcerecord or Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA etc.

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue as well. This module is part of RSAT. If you only want the `get-dnsserverresourcerecord` or `Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA`, that is in the feature `Rsat.Dns.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0`.

From an elevated prompt in PowerShell:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.Dns.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0
```

If you want all of the RSAT features:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Verified in PowerShell 7.2.5

Found this information here:
https://mikefrobbins.com/2018/10/03/use-powershell-to-install-the-remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-on-windows-10-version-1809/

Comment: Should have mentioned that I'm using Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlets are in the DNSServer module.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

get-dnsserverresourcerecord

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/get-dnsserverresourcerecord?view=windowsserver2022-ps

add-dnsserverresourcerecorda

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecorda?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: that part I understood, but there is no DNSserver module if don't install it. 

The question here is, how to install this module?
As I said, the script will do this, so needs to make sure that the module is installed so that can use these cmdlets.

Comment: Are this cmdlets only available in servers that have DNS installed?

Comment: @NoWay no, they can run on machines that have either the Dns server role, OR the Server Tools part of Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

The latter is option is used above in the accepted answer, you can install the capability to any machine